# How can I use Google's API in Xamarin for an iOS app using C# (not Obj-C)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, google-api, google-sheets

I want to be able to use Google's API to communicate with a Google Spreadsheet within an iOS application that I'm building in Xamarin.  I am familiar with C# but not Obj-C, hence why I'm using Xamarin (C#) and not Xcode (Obj-C).

I have found the .NET installation instructions at the link below but it is a .msi file for Windows only and I'm using a Mac so I don't know how to install it and use it within Xamarin (or even if that's possible!).

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#setting_up_your_client_library

I have found the Obj-C library available here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

But if it can be avoided I'd much prefer to do it all in C# / Xamarin.  If it can't be done then that's fine I just need to know if it can be as I'd much prefer to do it that way.

If I absolutely have to to do it by using the Obj-C Google library then is that doable when mainly creating the app from Xamarin?  Are there any major considerations or issues that I might find?

Any thoughts or help is much appreciated, thanks.

[Xamarin forum post: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9476/how-can-i-use-google-s-api-in-xamarin-for-an-ios-app-using-c-not-obj-c?new=1 ]

Answer (score -1):

C# API for google spreadsheet is poor and not very fast. Maybe the best way is creating script on google side.  Just create project from google disk. There will be a lot of tutorials. Unfortunately, it will be not c#, but Javascript, but it is pretty easy and you can send data in this script via POST and GET.